# Перенос кода из C++ в C (СИ)

Tags: c++, c, строки

Пытаюсь переписать этот код, написанный на C++ в C (СИ)
Код делает следующее: читает str2 если находит * читает str1 от позиции * до ближайшей **<** потом прибавляет **,**

Результат: Test_Value,564,Test_Value2,456,Test_Value3,123,

```
int main()
{

    std::string make_string{};
    std::string final_string{};
    std::string str1("<tr> <th>Test_Value</th> <th>564</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>"); 
    std::string str2("<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>");
    size_t i = 0;
    i = str2.find("*", i);
    int position = i;
    auto count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        while (str1[position] != '<') //читаем от позиции * до позицици <
        {
            make_string += str1[position]; // сохранить в переменную
            position++; // увеличить позицию на 1
        } // повторить цикл

        i = str2.find('*', i + 1); // найти позицию следующей звезды
        if (i > str1.length()) // если звездочек больше нет, выйти из цикла
            break;

        final_string += make_string + ','; //записать в основную строку и поставить запятую
        make_string.clear(); // очистить временную строку

        count += 2;
        position = i + (final_string.length() - count); // вычисляем позицию для следующей итерации так: позиция следующей звездочки известна (20) прибавим длину записанных символов и вычтем * и ,

    }
    final_string += make_string;

    cout << final_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Переделал вот так для СИ.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *make_string = NULL;
        char *final_string = NULL;

        char *str1[] = "<tr> <th>Test_Value</th> <th>564</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>";
        char *str2[] = "<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>";
        size_t i = 0;
        char *ptr = strchr(str2, '*');
        i = ptr - str2; // нашли позицию *
        int position = i; 
        int count = 0;
        for (ptr = str2; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++) { // читаем строку посимвольно передвигаем указатель
            if (*ptr == '*') { // нашли звезду -> установили указатель на позицию *

                --->
            }
            memset(&make_string, '\0', sizeof(char*)); //make_string = "";              
        }
        strcat(final_string, make_string);  //final_string += make_string;
        printf("%s\n",final_string);
        return 0;
}
```

Вопросы: ---> здесь нужно читать от позиции * до < в str1.

Как переместить указатель на туже позицию где он стоит в str2?

Comment: Для начала, `strchr` возвращает указатель, а не позицию (т.е. надо пересчитывать). Звезду после while можно искать им же. Естественно, если накапливать символы в `make_string`, то `realloc` нужен, однако дело в том, что накапливать их там не надо. Достаточно запоминать позиции начала и конца копируемого текста в `str1[]`, затем его можно добавлять к `final_string` (вот тут и нужен realloc)(впрочем, если у вас есть представление о размере str1, то возможно, лучше выделить память под final_string один раз, в самом начале). И не делайте дурацких вызовов strcat и strlen внутри  циклов

Comment: Судя по `strcat` у вас в коде, вы уже знаете, что в С строки через `+` или `+=` конкатенировать не получится. Почему тогда в цикле у вас по-прежнему болтается какое-то `make_string += ...`?

Comment: Потому что не могу переделать цикл while. В этом вопрос.

Comment: @avp Да, пересчитал позицию, вместо указателя. Т.е теперь мне нужно передвинуть указатель до '<' (как это сделать?) и сделать strncpy?

Comment: @avp к сожалению, размера final_string даже примерно сказать невозможно, нужно делать realloc.

Comment: Как передвинуть указатель? Проще всего идти по строке, увеличивая указатель и анализировать символы под ним (но при желании, естественно, можно искать тем же `strchr`). По поводу "даже примерно сказать невозможно" позвольте не проверить. Общее количество символов, которые могут оказаться в `final_string` не больше, чем их количество в `str1[]` (откуда вы их копируете). И где-то в программе вы ее заполняли, т.о. максимальный размер `final_string` очевиден

Comment: Обновил код чтением строки посимвольно.

Comment: У вас результат не соответствует словам, описывающим алгоритм в начале текста вопроса. Похоже, что  чтение из str1 с позиции звездочки в str2 относится *только к первой звездочке*... Видимо для остальных звездочек правило должно быть другим. Что-то вроде -- ищем очередную звездочку в str2 (прошли n символов), смещаемся на n в str1 и выводим текст до `<`. При этом новая позиция в str1 остается на символе `<`   (кстати, для первой звездочки это правило тоже подходит). Так?

Comment: @avp Описал полностью в комментариях

Comment: Вам программу или советы? Если советы, то я бы  просто читал строки символ за символом и проверял одну на звездочки, а другую на `'<'`. Это потому, что в str1 нельзя сразу прыгать на  позицию звездочки в str2, поскольку она может оказаться короче (из-за ошибки формата входных данных). Т.е. проверять в ней надо все символы на конец строки. Или в начале надо вызвать strlen(str1), но это не спортивно, мы как бы 2 раза одни и те же байты будем перебирать, да и в алгоритм постоянные проверки полезут...

Comment: Программу,  на чистом C. Не могу въехать, уже который день бъюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
 char *make_string = NULL;
 char *final_string = NULL;

 char str1[] = "<tr> <th>Test_Value</th> <th>564</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>";
 char str2[] = "<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>";
 size_t i = 0;
 size_t i2=0;
 size_t str1_length=strlen(str1);
 size_t str2_length=strlen(str2);
 size_t final_string_length=0;
 //указатель на * в str2
 char *ptr2 = strchr(str2, '*');
 //указатель на < в str1
 char *ptr1=NULL;

 size_t position = ptr2-str2;
   size_t count = 0;
 while (ptr2!=NULL) { // пока находится указатель на звёздочку в str2
   //позиция *
   i=ptr2-str2;
   //ищем < в str1
   if(position<str1_length)
   {
     ptr1=strchr(str1+position,'<');
   }else ptr1=NULL;
   if(ptr1!=NULL)//если найден <
   {
     size_t substr_length=ptr1-(str1+position);
     //position=position+substr_length;
     make_string=(char*)realloc(make_string,substr_length+1);
     strncpy(make_string,str1+position,substr_length);
     make_string[substr_length]='\0';
     //TODO:соединить с final_string
     size_t comma_length=1;
     if(final_string==NULL) comma_length=0;
     final_string=(char*)realloc(final_string,final_string_length+substr_length+1+comma_length);
     final_string[final_string_length]='\0';
     if(comma_length) final_string=strcat(final_string,",");
     final_string=strcat(final_string,make_string);
     final_string_length=final_string_length+substr_length+1;


     //увеличиваем позицию начала поиска звёздочки
     i=i+1;
     //ищем следующую *
     if(i<str2_length)
     {

       ptr2 = strchr(str2+i, '*');
       i=ptr2-str2;
       count=count+2;
         position = i + (final_string_length - count);
     }else ptr2=NULL;
   }else ptr2=NULL;//дальше искать нет смысла
 }
 //добавляем последнюю запятую
 final_string=(char*)realloc(final_string,final_string_length+1);
 final_string[final_string_length]='\0';
 final_string=strcat(final_string,",");

 printf("%s\n",final_string);
 //TODO: освободить память
 free(make_string);
 free(final_string);
 return 0;
}
```

Более устойчивый к пробелам из первой и второй строки алгоритм:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *make_string = NULL;
    char *final_string = NULL;
    size_t final_string_length=0;

    char str1[] = "<tr> <th>Test_Value_Very_Big_Big_value_VALUE</th>     <th>564</th>     </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr >         <tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>";
    char str2[] = "< tr > < th >*    </th> <th  >*</th> </tr         >           <tr> <th>*</th> <th>*  </th> </tr>     <tr> <th> *</th> <th>*      </th> </tr>";

    size_t str1_length=strlen(str1);
    size_t str2_length=strlen(str2);
    size_t substr_length=0;
    int more1_count=0;
    int more2_count=0;
    char *more1_last=NULL;//позиция последнего '>' в str1
    char *less1=NULL;//позиция '<' в str1
    int i2=0;//текущая позиция в str2
    int i1=0;//текущая позиция в str1
    size_t comma_length=0;
    for(i2=0;i2<str2_length;++i2)
    {
        switch(str2[i2])
        {
        case '>':
            more2_count++;
            if(more1_count<more2_count)
            {
                more1_last=strchr(str1+i1,'>');
                if(!more1_last) break;//соответствующий '>' не найден, заканчиваем перебор
                i1=more1_last-str1+1;//передвигаем позицию в str1 на знак за '>'
                more1_count++;
            }
            break;
        case '*':
            if(!more1_last) break;//не было '>' в str1 - некорректные входные данные
            less1=strchr(more1_last,'<');
            if(!less1) break;//нет '<' str1 в str1 - некорректные входные данные
            substr_length=less1-more1_last-1;
            make_string=(char*)realloc(make_string,substr_length+1);
            strncpy(make_string,more1_last+1,substr_length);
            make_string[substr_length]='\0';
            //TODO:соединить с final_string
            if(final_string) comma_length=1;
            final_string=(char*)realloc(final_string,final_string_length+substr_length+1+comma_length);
            final_string[final_string_length]='\0';
            if(comma_length) final_string=strcat(final_string,",");
            final_string=strcat(final_string,make_string);
            final_string_length=final_string_length+substr_length+1;
            break;

        }
    }
    //добавляем последнюю запятую
    final_string=(char*)realloc(final_string,final_string_length+1);
    final_string[final_string_length]='\0';
    final_string=strcat(final_string,",");

    printf("%s\n",final_string);

    //TODO: освободить память
    free(make_string);
    free(final_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не известно сколько букв и сколько чисел, поэтому дополнительные пробелы не годятся.

Comment: @GarfieldCat уже понял, что немного другой алгоритм.

Comment: @GarfieldCat посмотрите новый вариант. Работает с исходными данными.

Comment: Если строчку сделать так:char str1[] = "<tr> <th>Test_Value_Very_Big_Big_value_VALUE</th> <th>564</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>"; то получится так Test_Value_Very_Big_Big_value_VALUE,e2,/tr>,est_Value3,

Comment: @GarfieldCat Согласен с Вами, что новая позиция начала поиска звёздочки была неправильна. Исправил. Простая инкрементация на единицу, приводит к выводу корректного результата для указанной в комментарии str1. Это осталось от алгоритма, где я вторую строчку добивал пробелами.

Comment: @GarfieldCat Добавил ещё один вариант алгоритма, устойчывый к пробелам из первой и второй строк входных данных.

Answer (score 1):

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc obtain_text.c -Wall && ./a.out
Test_Value,564,Test_Value2,456,Test_Value3,123,
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat obtain_text.c
```

Поправил немного прошлую версию  и добавил комментариев

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// тут realloc-ом собираем результат (кусочки текста и запятые)
struct result {
  char *str;
  int capacity, // сколько памяти всего выделено
    size;       // сколько байт накоплено в str
};

// добавим символ в конец накапливаемого результата
// завершающий 0 не заносим, поэтому его надо добавлять на верхнем уровне
static inline char *
add_char (struct result *r, char c)
{
  if (r->size >= r->capacity - 1)
    if (!(r->str = realloc(r->str, r->capacity *= 2)))
      return 0; // ENOMEM
  r->str[r->size++] = c;

  return r->str;
}

// пропустим заданное число символов
// скопируем символы текста до завешающего `<` в результат
// при пропуске и копировании анализируем источник на завершающий 0
// возвращаем адрес найденного `<` или завершающего 0-ля,
//   т.е. адрес, с которого начинается поиск следующего кусочка результата
static const char *
add_text (struct result *r, const char *src_text, int nskip)
{
  for (; nskip && *src_text; nskip--)
    src_text++;

  while (*src_text && *src_text != '<')
    if (!add_char(r, *src_text++))
      return 0; // out of memory

  return src_text;
}


// returns comma separeted text in dynamic memory
// or NULL on ENOMEM
char *
obtain_text (const char *text, const char *pattern)
{
  int nskip;
  struct result result = {malloc(16), 16, 0};
  if (!result.str)
    return 0; // ENOMEM


  for (nskip = 0; *pattern; nskip++, pattern++) 
    if (*pattern == '*') {
      // найдено начало очередного фрагмента текста в nskip символах от text
      if (!(text = add_text(&result, text, nskip)) || !add_char(&result, ','))
        return 0;
      nskip = -1;
    }

  // завершим изготовление результата
  //  (add_char(), добавлявший символы, не записывает завершающий 0)
  result.str[result.size] = 0;
  return realloc(result.str, result.size + 1);
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str1[] = "<tr> <th>Test_Value</th> <th>564</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value2</th> <th>456</th> </tr><tr> <th>Test_Value3</th> <th>123</th> </tr>";
  char str2[] = "<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr><tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>";

  char *str = obtain_text(str1, str2);
  // Test_Value,564,Test_Value2,456,Test_Value3,123,
  if (str) {
    puts(str);
    free(str);
  } else
    exit((perror("obtain_text"), 1));

  return 0;
}
```