# По шаблону читается только первая строка

Tags: c, строки

По ответу на [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/792443/212222) вопрос делал следующую программу. Она читает из массива строк строки с шаблоном (lines_temp) и сравнивает их с полученными из файла (lines_down).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *substring(const char *str, size_t begin, size_t len) {
    if (str == 0 || strlen(str) == 0 || strlen(str) < begin ||
        strlen(str) < (begin + len))
        return 0;

    return strndup(str + begin, len);
}

int main() {
    char *make_string = NULL;
    char *final_string = NULL;
    char **lines_down = (char *[]){"<tr> <th>Test_Value_1</th> <th>4334</th> </tr>",
                              "<tr> <th>Test_Value_2</th> <th>5467</th> </tr>",
                              "<tr> <th>Test_Value_3</th> <th>34543</th> </tr>",
                              NULL
                             };
    char **lines_temp = (char *[]){"!#<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>",
                              "!#<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>",
                              "!#<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>",
                              NULL
                             };

    char *substr_temp = NULL;
    size_t comma_length = 1;
    size_t final_string_length = 0;
    while (*lines_temp && *lines_down) {
        if (strstr(*lines_temp, "!#") != NULL) {
            substr_temp = substring(*lines_temp, 2, strlen(*lines_temp) - 2);
            size_t i = 0;
            size_t i2 = 0;
            size_t str1_length = strlen(*lines_down);
            size_t str2_length = strlen(substr_temp);
            char *ptr2 = strchr(substr_temp, '*'); //указатель на * в str2
            char *ptr1 = NULL; //указатель на < в str1

            size_t position = ptr2 - substr_temp;
            size_t count = 0;
            while (ptr2 != NULL) { // пока находится указатель на звёздочку в str2
                //позиция *
                i = ptr2 - substr_temp;
                //ищем < в str1
                if (position < str1_length) {
                    ptr1 = strchr(*lines_down + position, '<');
                } else ptr1 = NULL;
                if (ptr1 != NULL)//если найден <
                {
                    // ==========================================
                    // на четвертой итерации здесь копируется мусор, а потом Test_Value_3 вместо 5467
                    size_t substr_length = ptr1 - (*lines_down + position); // строка под звездочкой
                    make_string = realloc(make_string, substr_length + 1); // выделить память для подстроки плюс нулевой символ
                    strncpy(make_string, *lines_down + position, substr_length); // скопироовать в make_string строку под звездочкой из исходной строки (lines_down + позиция *)
                    make_string[substr_length] = '\0'; // добавить строку под звездочкой в make_string

                    //скопировать в финальную строку и добавить запятую в конец
                    final_string = realloc(final_string, final_string_length + substr_length + comma_length + 1); // память длина final_string + длина строки под звездочкой + запятая + нулевой символ
                    final_string[final_string_length] = '\0'; // добавить нулевой символ
                    final_string = strcat(final_string, make_string); // копируем make_string в final_string
                    final_string = strcat(final_string, ","); // добавляем запятую
                    final_string_length = final_string_length + substr_length + 1; // считам новую длину строки final_string
                    i++; //увеличиваем позицию начала поиска звёздочки

                    if (i < str2_length) { //ищем следующую *
                        ptr2 = strchr(substr_temp + i, '*');
                        i = ptr2 - substr_temp;
                        count = count + 2;
                        position = i + (final_string_length - count);
                    } else ptr2 = NULL;
                } else ptr2 = NULL;//дальше искать нет смысла


            }
            //добавляем последнюю запятую
            final_string = realloc(final_string, final_string_length + 1);
            final_string[final_string_length] = '\0';
            final_string = strcat(final_string, ",");
        }

        ++lines_down;
        ++lines_temp;
    }
    printf("%s\n", final_string);
    return 0;
}
```

**Результат работы программы:** Test_Value_1,4334,Test_Value_2,Test_Value_3,,

**Ожидаемый результат:** Test_Value_1,4334,Test_Value_2,5467,Test_Value_3,34543,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрел я на этот код, прослезился, попробовал быстро поправить и понял, что в такой лапше ничего нельзя сделать.

1. Вначале добавим немного вызовов free - память никто не освобождает. Это конечно на багу не влияет, но все же.
2. Потом решил вынести внутренности цикла в отдельную функцию Пусть она парсит по одной паре строк и выдает результат. Это помогло определить, что где то вылазили за пределы массива (место потерялось). То есть, на этом этапе бага ушла. Точное место мне не понятно до конца.
3. Потом пошел легкий рефакторинг, потом сильнее.

Итак, что тесть. К примеру, для строки make_string применяется realloc (который кстати, не совсем верно написан), хотя на самом деле можно было бы просто по месту выделить память или даже использовать просто strndup.

realloc нужно проверять на возвращаемый результат. конструкция вида `x = ralloc(x, ...)` хоть и компилируется и работает, но является признаком проблемы.

функция `substring` вычисляет трижды длину строки, хотя последнее условие в if всегда будет истинно (из за предпоследнего). Но потом стало понятно, что эта функция не нужна.

код, который добавляет "последнюю запятую" - не нужен. Она и так есть.

для многих переменных удалось уменьшить область видимости, что позитивно сказалось на размере кода.

Многие танцы с удлинением строки можно убрать, если заведомо предположить длину строки. Это даже эффективнее с точки зрения оптимизации. Логично предположить, что строка не может быть длинее, чем двойная длина строки `lines_down`.

В целом, там ещё есть много места, где нужно улучшать (и код будет чище).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* do_string(char* lines_temp, char* lines_down)
{
    char* final_string = malloc(strlen(lines_down)*2+1);
    final_string[0] = '\0';
    if (strstr(lines_temp, "!#") != NULL) {
        char* substr_temp = lines_temp+2;
        size_t str1_length = strlen(lines_down);
        size_t str2_length = strlen(substr_temp);
        char *ptr2 = strchr(substr_temp, '*'); //указатель на * в str2

        size_t position = ptr2 - substr_temp;
        size_t count = 0;
        size_t final_string_length = 0;
        while (ptr2 != NULL) { // пока находится указатель на звёздочку в str2
            //позиция *
            size_t i = ptr2 - substr_temp;
            //ищем < в str1
            char *ptr1 = NULL; //указатель на < в str1
            if (position < str1_length) {
                ptr1 = strchr(lines_down + position, '<');
            }
            if (ptr1 != NULL)//если найден <
            {
                // ==========================================
                size_t substr_length = ptr1 - (lines_down + position); // строка под звездочкой
                char *make_string = strndup(lines_down+position, substr_length);// скопироовать в make_string строку под звездочкой из исходной   строки (lines_down + позиция *)

                //скопировать в финальную строку и добавить запятую в конец
                strcat(final_string, make_string); // копируем make_string в final_string
                free(make_string);
                strcat(final_string, ",");
                final_string_length = final_string_length + substr_length + 1; // считам новую длину строки final_string
                i++; //увеличиваем позицию начала поиска звёздочки

                if (i < str2_length) { //ищем следующую *
                    ptr2 = strchr(substr_temp + i, '*');
                    i = ptr2 - substr_temp;
                    count = count + 2;
                    position = i + (final_string_length - count);
                } else ptr2 = NULL;
            } else ptr2 = NULL;//дальше искать нет смысла


        }
        //free(substr_temp);
    }
    return final_string;
}

int main() {
    char *final_string = NULL;
    char **lines_down = (char *[]){"<tr> <th>Test_Value_1</th> <th>4334</th> </tr>",
                                   "<tr> <th>Test_Value_2</th> <th>5467</th> </tr>",
                                   "<tr> <th>Test_Value_3</th> <th>34543</th> </tr>",
                                   NULL
                                  };
    char **lines_temp = (char *[]){"!#<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>",
                                   "!#<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>",
                                   "!#<tr> <th>*</th> <th>*</th> </tr>",
                                   NULL
                                  };

    size_t final_string_length = 0;
    while (*lines_temp && *lines_down) {
        char* tmp = do_string(*lines_temp, *lines_down);
        // append this string to final
        size_t tmp_len = strlen(tmp);
        char* tmp_final_string = realloc(final_string, final_string_length+tmp_len+1);
        if (!tmp_final_string) {
            perror("Ups, can't realloc");
        }
        final_string = tmp_final_string;
        final_string[final_string_length] = '\0';
        strcat(final_string, tmp);
        final_string_length += tmp_len;
        free(tmp);
        ++lines_down;
        ++lines_temp;
    }
    printf("%s\n", final_string);
    free(final_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Основная ошибка:

На первый взгляд <s>эту лошадь, конечно, проще пристрелить</s> всё переписать с нуля, но всё же из спортивного интереса решил найти ошибку:

```
// ....
if (i < str2_length) { //ищем следующую *
    ptr2 = strchr(substr_temp + i, '*');
    i = ptr2 - substr_temp;
    count = count + 2;
    // !!! Здесь прибавляется длина всей уже отформатированной строки,
    //     а не длина обработанных подстрок на данной итерации !!!
    position = i + (final_string_length - count);
} else ptr2 = NULL;
```

То есть достаточно поправить всего две строчки:

```
if (i < str2_length) { //ищем следующую *
    ptr2 = strchr(substr_temp + i, '*');
    i = ptr2 - substr_temp;
    count += substr_length - 1;
    position = i + count;
} else ptr2 = NULL;
```

#### Другие ошибки:

- Из критического, только неверная аллокация:

  ```
  final_string = realloc(final_string, final_string_length + 1);
  final_string[final_string_length] = '\0';
  final_string = strcat(final_string, ",");
  ```

  т.к. добавляется терминирующий ноль и запятая, то должно быть `+2`, а не `+1`.
- Полное отсутствие освобождения памяти.
- Сомнительный алгоритм: обычно при сопоставлении строк шаблонам ищутся не только звёздочки и отмеряется расстояние между ними, а сравниваются все промежуточные токены.

#### Пожелания на будущее:

Стоит дробить код на функции это поможет избежать подобных трудноотлавливыемых ошибок и даст возможность намного проще их локализовывать.